# "Rechnung" vs. "Faktur" for an invoice

Tags: english-to-german, difference, word-choice

What's the most commonly used word used to mean invoice?

What's the difference in meaning between *Rechnung* and *Faktur*?

Comment: Your question would be better if you could show some research and ask what specifically is not clear to you.

Comment: My research is that of looking at several very simple English-to-German dictionaries and not being sure what the difference in those terms is, what contexts they are being used in, and whether one is more appropriate in some situations.

Answer (score 7):

The most commonly used word for the english term "invoice" is:

> **Rechnung**

The word "Faktur" is in my opinion kind of obsolete and barely ever used nowadays.

**Dict.cc:**
[image: Screenshot from Dict.cc]

**Lingue:**
[image: Screenshot from Lingue]

Reference 1: https://www.dict.cc/?s=invoice

Reference 2: https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=invoice

Comment: Did you read this, or does it also come from personal experience?

Comment: Both :) On the one hand you can see it in the screenshot I have embedded. I don't know exactly what the metadata with the number stands for, but I guess the higher the number, the more often it is used as translation (I think it's based on any search results for translations or maybe any rating). On the other hand I am German and the term "Faktur" is a pretty rare word to me.

Comment: I'm Austrian and I haven't ever heard of nor used the term "Faktur".

(I have used "F**r**aktur", which means *fracture*. )

Comment: @Stefan_Fairphone, nor have I as someone from Eastern Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with SteffPoints Answer regarding "Faktura". In business in general this is a very well known word, used in everyday language. But you need to distinguish:

`Rechnung` is mostly the paper / pdf / document that is sent to somebody.

`Faktura` is the *process* of creating that document.

Seeing that special meaning it is normal, that someone who has nothing to do with writing invoices does not know that meaning and thinks it is "barely used".

As I am not a native english speaker, I have no idea, if "invoice" really has both meanings in english, but if it has, then the translation for the different meanings are correct.

Comment: The process of creating the document is called [Fakturierung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fakturierung) . Faktura is the result. However i agree, that "Faktura" and "Fakturierung" are well known business words (e.g. when you are using SAP)

Comment: OK. then the usage of the word is wrong here in our company... As for us the monthly "Faktura" is creating all the invoices for all of our customers...

Comment: And the OP asked for "Faktur" and not for "Faktur**a**".

Comment: So what? Faktur and Faktura are the same word just from different countries...